# How to find and disable precedence policy that grays out "Log on as a batch job" policy

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, group-policy

After a lot of digging, using rsop.msc, I have come to the conclusion, that the precedence policy `PC - Windows 10 - OS - Global - (release v3.14) - CU` prevents `Log on as a batch job` policy from being edited in gpedit.msc.

I cannot seem to find `PC - Windows 10 - OS - Global - (release v3.14) - CU` in gpedit.msc using its very limited search capabilities.

How do I locate and disable this precedence policy locally using Administrative privileges?

[image]

Comment: Is this computer on a domain? That policy name might be the name of a Group Policy object in Active Directory.

Comment: @BenN - might be. How do I disable policies from AD using local administrator privileges?

Comment: You could fiddle with the Registry, but the domain policy will probably just reapply. If your computer is a member of a domain, you need to talk to a domain administrator (your IT department).

Comment: @BenN - could you elaborate on where to edit the registry to temporarily disable domain group policies? Is it possible to stay in a domain, but block domain group policies from being applied on restarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caution!** If your computer is managed by an IT department, your company might not be very pleased with you circumventing IT policy. You should try to talk to a domain administrator first.

It turns out that you can alter privilege assignments with the appropriate API even in the presence of a policy. To do that from the command line, you can use the NTRights utility from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657). Use this command to grant the batch logon right:

```
ntrights -u USERNAME +r SeBatchLogonRight
```

Replace `USERNAME` with the desired user or group. The change will take effect at the next logon of the affected user. The Local Security Policy snap-in will reflect the change but still not allow you to graphically edit the setting. The domain policy can reapply after an edit to that GPO, a `gpupdate /force`, or a reboot. You might need to create a scheduled task to run that NTRights command at system start.

Comment: Thank you. But it is NOT possible to completely get rid of those domain policies - you can only modify them?

Comment: @Shuzheng For policies in the Administrative Templates branch of the Registry, it's very easy to remove them (temporarily at least), but User Rights Assignment uses a different mechanism. With a lot of fiddling one might be able to remove the bookkeeping on the GPO responsible, but doing that such that it can't just reapply will almost certainly break any other policy updates. The strategy I described is effective (at least temporarily) and non-invasive.

Comment: Thank you - what does GPO stand for?

Comment: @Shuzheng "Group Policy Object" - a domain can have many GPOs; the policies applied to a specific computer/user are the combination of the settings from the GPOs that apply to it.

Comment: Are those policies that you enable yourself using gpedit.msc also called “GPOs”? Or does that term only apply to the policies coming from the domain?

Comment: @Shuzheng The Local Group Policy Editor edits the local GPO, so yes to your first question. (There can also be multiple per-user local GPOs, though the existence of these is slightly obscure.)